# how to pause the game to handle user input

Tags: java, libgdx, scene2d

I'm facing a problem since many days without finding an anwser.

In the code i will not put all my code because it will just complicate the question.

I have a game class which is rendering each frame.

```
    public class MyGame implements ApplicationListener {

    @Override
    public void render() {
         //handling event
        handleEvent();
        //update player position
        updatePlayerPosition();
        //rendering the player using a batch
        renderPlayer();

    }

public void handleEvent(){
   //when the player prees on C i'm calling a method in another class 
   // when i do some processing
   if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.C)) {
       OtherClassForProcessing() ocp = new OtherClassForProcessing();
       ocp.process();
    }
}

    //in this method i have to ask the user to choose an option 
    //i have to think to stop running this method until the
   // user choose      an option
    //this method has to return a value
    public static int displayChoice(List<Integer> ListOfInteger){
        return 0;
    }



}


public Class OtherClassForProcessing(){
   public void process(){
     int value= MyGame.displayChoice() ;
   }

}
```

The question  is how can i ask the user to choose an option in the displayChoice method.

What kind of widget will do this work.

I tried to use another screen for that , but the methode don't stop running .

How can i ask the program to stop until the user choose an option.

Thank you

**what i tried is** :

```
@Override
public static int displayChoice(List<Integer> ListOfInteger){
     //i change the screen when i ask the user to choose from many options
    setScreen(new PauseScreen());
    a wile loop hwo run until the user choose an option from the other screen 
    while(PauseScreen.notYetChoosen){
        Gdx.app.log("display message ", "the user not yet choose an ption");
    }
    return PauseScreenValue;
}
```

When i put the while loop:

- the screen don't change from the game to the PauseScreen.
- the loop run without stoping
- the screen block

But when i remove the while loop the screen change to the PauseScreen but the method finish without waiting the user to choose an option.

**EDIT**
i tried to avoid using another screen unfortunantly even when i used a window the screen block

Comment: You could put even less code to simplify the question if you used `ApplicationAdapter` and removed the empty overridden methods. Some of us look at questions on our phones - scrolling code is horrible!

Comment: ok andy i removed the empty method. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use a separate screen for this, I do not know your code structure exactly but here is how you can do it conceptually if you were trying to get input from a "pop up" or "pause screen" or something of that nature.

Inside of your Game Screen have a boolean which will be set when your "pop up" is displayed, for example `isPaused`, then you can use this boolean to skip over game logic while waiting for the screen to receive input.

For a more elegant approach you can use `Game States` which can represent which state your game is in. You can have a PLAYING state, GETTING_INPUT state, etc. Then you can run game logic depending on which state you are in.

**EXAMPLE:**

```
public void update (float deltaTime) {
        if (deltaTime > 0.1f) deltaTime = 0.1f;

        switch (state) {
        case GAME_READY:
            updateReady();
            break;
        case GAME_RUNNING:
            updateRunning(deltaTime);
            break;
        case GAME_PAUSED:
            updatePaused();
            break;
        case GAME_LEVEL_END:
            updateLevelEnd();
            break;
        case GAME_OVER:
            updateGameOver();
            break;
        }
    }
```

**EXAMPLE SOURCE AND MORE INFO:**
LIBGDX SuperJumper Demo

https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx-demo-superjumper/blob/master/core/src/com/badlogicgames/superjumper/GameScreen.java

**Response to your edit**

The reason your code is not changing is because you have a while loop printing out to the Gdx Log until input is taken so your code is stuck in that while loop.

If you want to go this route, you can set a 'pause' variable inside your Game Screen to true and then set your screen to the pause screen. Inside of your Game Screens update logic, tell it not to update if paused.

```
  public void update()
  { 
       if(!paused)
       {
          //game logic
       }
  }
```

Comment: i think i did the same thing but it didn't work i will edit my question to show you my try

Comment: Check my update for an example on using game states, it will be your best bet as it is an official Libgdx example.

Comment: as i said when i change the screen , just the show,resize are called from the PauseScreen , the render method is not called and it's strange.it's called just when i delete the loop from the method

Comment: how canI  run a while loop in screen A and having a screen B running his render method.i think i had to deal with multithreading.

Comment: Did you check the example code I posted? You should just have one update method for the entire game and simply change the logic that it executes depending on the state of the game.

Comment: yes i saw the example , but the problem is  not in the update method , the update method  would be called just if i finish the processing of my displaychoice method.